# Algorithm to find a point where cost of moving is minimized

Tags: java, algorithm

There are some n number of points situated in a 2d grid. Requirement is to move one item from all those points (n-1 points) to a single point (in the set of n points) so that cost of moving all items to that point will be the minimum. If there are more than one such point then we can select any point randomly. The cost of moving is calculated as follows.

**Formula for cost calulation**

> if there is a point in `(x,y)` then the cost needed to move the object from `(x,y)` to all the 8 adjacent points `{(x+1,y),(x+1,y+1),(x,y+1),(x-1,y+1),(x,y-1),(x-1,y-1),(x,y-1),(x+1,y-1)}` is 1 unit

Can anybody suggest any O(N) algorithm for this? I have tried the O(N2) algorithms (like taking each pair and calculating the cost).

Comment: Why the Java tag? If this is homework, please consider adding the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: Might be better suited for Math.StackExchange?

Comment: @Alexis this is not a typical homework problem.Since i tried this algorithm in java a added it as well

Comment: @Alok But since you ask for an algorithm, this will be language agnostic.

Comment: WHat is the cost to move if there is no point at coordinates?

Comment: @Hurda we are moving to the points where the objects are existing. If it is a void then there is no point of moving items there. You can think this in an alternate way. There are N storage houses and i want to dump one item from each storage house to one particular storage house such that total cost of moving is minimum

Comment: @Alok so each coordinate that you want to move through has to be ocuppied by point? I assume that object == item in your question. So we can assume that all points are interconnected through other points?

Comment: @Hurda why are you thinking of inter connectivity. Lets think it in a simpler way. I just want to find that storehouse where the cost of moving items from other n-1 storehouses will be minimum.No matter which point you choose, whether it is occupied or empty doesn't matter.All you need is finding one or more such points in the set of points.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to move all points to a "center" where center is defined as the point with minimal total cost value.  For three points, I think the answer is near the centroid of the triangle.  The centroid is the point we get by simply averaging all 3 x values and all three y values.

Expanding beyond three points, I think the average points is either the right answer or near the right answer.  If you were using the Euclidean distance formula bewtween points, then I'm fairly certain that the point you seek is just the average. But you are using some modified taxi-cab geometry which makes 45 degree angles count "less" than they should.  The cost from (0,0) to (5,5) is 5 by your definition, instead of 5 sqrt(5) (about 40% more) using standard geometry.  But for a horizontal or vertical move, the metrics are the same.  So how far apart is the right answer from my quick guess? If you can get some esitimate on the radius, then I suggest this algorithm:

- Computer average point ( runs in O(n) time)

  ```
  C = new Point(average(xVals), average(yVals))
  ```

  Computer radius - some estimate of how far the real answer is from the quick Euclidean answer.

  Consider all point in that radius and see if they yield a lower total cost than C.

This last item runs in O(r^2), and as long as you can show that r is much less than n you have a good solution.

Comment: Thom your suggestion is good but it will fail in a case where multiple points are in the same cordinate. And its not the centroid which is important to me, even if i choose the point which is closest to the centroid some test cases are failing.

Comment: I don't see why multiple points with the same coordinates moves the answer further from the centroid. It shouldn't affect the Euclidean case. As far as the real answer you are seeking is concerned, in general it will NOT be the centroid. But by looking at some examples, can u estimate how far the answer is from the centroid? This is maximum distance is what I am calling r in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could calculate the mass center of the n points in linear time, then calculate the closest point to that mass center in linear time also.

to get the mass center:

```
center = points[0];
for (int i=1; i<points.length; ++i) {
  center = massCenter(center, i+1, points[i]);
}

Point massCenter(Point currCent, int weight, Point p) {
  double x = (currCent.x * weight + p.x)/(weight+1);
  double y = (currCent.y * weight + p.y)/(weight+1);
  return new Point(x, y);
}
```

I assumed a double coordinate for the point for the sake of calculating the center correctly.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee that the center of mass will result in minimum cost.

Comment: @Alok - the center of mass _is_ minimal distance overall, so the movement cost should be minimal as well

Comment: Distance is defined differently in this question.  Alok is using a non-Euclidean distance.

Comment: @Thorn - you are correct, I did not take the diagonal movement having the same cost as vertical/horizontal into account

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that an O(n) solution is not possible.   If the input data set has all of the points approximating a circle, it seems likely that an algorithm will have to check every point to see if it is the best solution.

Now, there are probably good algorithms to handle "normal" cases in time proportional to n.
A O(N log N) heuristic for ordering the points for a best-first search seems likely.  A-star might even be possible, but seems more difficult.

Comment: could u explain any of the algorithm. I mean how to modify the above problem statement for these algorithms